# Unterschied zwischen "kostbar" und "wertvoll"

Tags: difference, adjective, meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern *kostbar* und *wertvoll*?

Beide bezeichnen nach meinem Verständnis eine Sache, die einen gewissen finanziellen, ideellen oder persönlichen Wert hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Kostbar* betont den Wert etwas stärker als *wertvoll*. Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kostbar) benutzt zur Beschreibung ***sehr** wertvoll* [Hervorhebung von mir], das deutet die Richtung schon an.

Beispiel:

> Die Juwelen sind wertvoll.

Das ist fast schon eine Platitüde – welche Juwelen sind es nicht? Erst

> Die Juwelen sind kostbar.

hebt sie als etwas Besonderes hervor.

> Dieser Film ist künstlerisch wertvoll.

Dieses Prädikat wird manchen Filmen verliehen, um auszudrücken, dass sie überhaupt einen *künstlerischen* Wert haben (und nicht nur reine Unterhaltungsware sind). Hier wäre

> Dieser Film ist künstlerisch kostbar.

viel zu hochgestochen. Für mein Empfinden klingt dieser Satz schon deshalb falsch, weil das zusätzliche Adjektiv das Herausragende von *kostbar* schon wieder relativiert.

Answer (score 2):

Kostbar hat, gegenüber wertvoll, in der Regel noch den Zusatz eines ideellen Wertes: Es ist nicht nur viel Geld wert, es bedeutet (jemandem) auch viel.